# Enable 'mod_rewrite' Using .htaccess File On cPanel Shared Hosting Server

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using cPanel to host my website. I need to enable 'mod_rewrite' on this Shared Hosting cPanel account to run my script. I've tried to Google the solutions high and low but did not find any luck yet.

Those tutorials that I found only work well with VPS and some of them said that, only hosting provider can change and enable it. But, some of them said that, it can be done easily by editing the .htaccess file.

My question:
If I want to edit the .htaccess file, what should I include in that file?
What the 'rules' and 'conditions' that should be included?

Answer (score 4):

cPanel is not inherently involved here, by the way.

Do you actually know if you're allowed to do this? Not all hosts allow such config changes via .htaccess. You should probably contact support to check.

*If* you already know it's possible, you can add:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

to your .htaccess file. Just put it near the top so it's before any rewrite rules.

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks` must also be enabled, if it not already.